# prove logic equivalence: $(a∧¬b)∨(¬c∧¬a) ≡ (a→b)→¬(c∨a)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hello we are asked to prove the logic equivalence of $(a∧¬b)∨(¬c∧¬a) ≡ (a→b)→¬(c∨a)$ by using the Laws from the Table of Logical Equivalences. We also have to write the name of the law used at each step (one one law at each step!)

I have tried to simplify the second part $(a→b)→¬(c∨a)$ to see if it's the same with the first part. Here is my solution so far: [in the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mutkR.jpg).

But finally I got $(a∨¬b)∨(¬c∨¬a)$, it seems very different than the first part $(a∧¬b)∨(¬c∧¬a)$. What do I missed in my solution here?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the cat that  (a ∧ ¬b) is equiv to ¬(a → b)

Comment: Your mistakes are in the 3rd and 5th lines; check your table more carefully to see how to negate a disjunction (an 'or' formula).

Comment: $p \implies q \equiv q \lor \lnot p$ helps translate implications into purely and/or statements.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do it step by step.

1. Find a connection between $(a \land \lnot b)$ and $(a \rightarrow b)$. If we make a truth table, we get
   $$\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
   & a & b & {\lnot b} & a \land \lnot b & a \rightarrow b \\ \hline & F & F & T & F & T
   \\ & F & T & F & F & T
   \\ & T & F & T & T & F
   \\ & T & T & F & F & T
   \end{array}$$

You can see that $(a \land \lnot b)$ = $\lnot(a \rightarrow b)$ as mentioned by @Mauro ALLEGRANZA

2. Using the $1.$ De Morgan's law, we have $\lnot c \land \lnot a = \lnot(c \lor a)$.

If we insert this in into your logic equivalence, we get $$ \lnot(a \rightarrow b) \lor \lnot(c \lor a) \equiv (a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow \lnot(c \lor a) $$

3. Make a "variable" change. Let $\lnot(a \rightarrow b) = \lnot d$ and $\lnot(c \lor a) = \lnot e$. Then, your logic equivalence will be $$\lnot d \lor \lnot e \equiv d \rightarrow \lnot e$$

Let's make another truth table which looks as follows:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
& d & e & \lnot d & \lnot e & \lnot d \lor \lnot e & d \rightarrow \lnot e \\ \hline & F & F & T & T & T & T 
\\ & F & T & T & F & T & T
\\ & T & F & F & T & T & T
\\ & T & T & F & F & F & F
\end{array}$$

The truth table shows that indeed $$\lnot d \lor \lnot e \equiv d \rightarrow \lnot e$$ holds.

4. Switch $d$ and $e$ with the original variables, so $\lnot d = \lnot (a \rightarrow b) = (a \land \lnot b)$ and $\lnot e = \lnot (c \lor a) = (\lnot c \land \lnot a)$ and you have $$(a \land \lnot b) \lor (\lnot c \land \lnot a) \equiv (a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow \lnot (c \lor a)$$ proven.

Comment: @311411 yes, that was a mistake. I meant $a \land \lnot b$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are truth tables required?

$\lnot(p\implies q) \equiv p \land \lnot q$ is Negation of the Conditional.

The negation of that is $(p\implies q) \equiv q \lor \lnot p$

$(a \land \lnot b) \lor (\lnot c \land \lnot a)\equiv (a \land \lnot b )\lor \lnot (c \lor a)$ by DeMorgan's Law on the right most term.

$(a \land \lnot b) \lor (\lnot c \land \lnot a)\equiv \lnot(a \implies b) \lor \lnot (c \lor a)$ by Negation of the Conditional for the a,b term.

$(a \land \lnot b) \lor (\lnot c \land \lnot a)\equiv (a \implies b) \implies \lnot (c \lor a)$ *

*Let $q=\lnot(c \lor a)$ and $p=(a \implies b )$ Then we have a statement in the form $\lnot p \lor q$ allowing us to use the negation of Negation of the Conditional, or equivalently, the re-expression of a conditional in terms of negation and or statement.